# Ansible wrongly complains about unquoted values

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have an Ansible setup like this:

`roles/myrole/defaults/main.yml`

```
some_flag: "False"
```

`roles/myrole/vars/some_env.yml`

```
SOME_FLAG: "{{ some_flag }}"
```

`roles/myrole/tasks/main.yml`

```
---
- name: Load env
  include_vars:
    file: "vars/some_env.yml"
    name: "some_env"

- name: Some Task
  docker_container:
    name: "some_container"
    image: "some_image"
    env: "{{ some_env }}"
```

All looks good here, everything is quoted (cf. also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56544069/539599)). Even so, Ansible (2.8.3) complains:

> fatal: [myhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Non-string value found for env option. Ambiguous env options must be wrapped in quotes to avoid them being interpreted. Key: SOME_FLAG"}

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

`"True"`, `'True'`, `"False"` and `'False'` (case sensitive) are **string** in YAML, but **boolean** in Ansible.

`"true"`, `"false"`, `"TRUE"`, `"FALSE"` and others are **string** in both YAML and Ansible.

Test it with the following playbook:

```
# test.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    b: "True"
    s: "true"
  tasks:
    - name: var:b
      debug:
        var: b

    - name: var:s
      debug:
        var: s
```

And check the result:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 
PLAY [localhost] ****************

TASK [var:b] ********************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "b": true
}

TASK [var:s] ********************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "s": "true"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************
localhost                  : ok=2
```

---

So to answer your question, if possible, use `some_flag: "false"` instead of `some_flag: "False"`.

If you have to use `"False"`, then you will need `"{{ some_flag | string }}"` when referencing it.

Note that `quote` filter won't work, as it's designed to quote variable for shell use when necessary, instead of simply quoting variable and escaping quotes inside.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what's happening where, but apparently somewhere in the replacement pipeline, `"False"` is parsed into a boolean.

Adding an extra set of escaped quotes helps:

`roles/myrole/defaults/main.yml`

```
some_flag: "\"False\""
```

Comment: FWIW, we have ports like `"8080"` going through the same pipeline and they don't cause any errors.

Comment: Only `docker_container.env` option will complain about non-string values as a safety precaution.